# datawarehouse: what is the technical name for two different dimensions consuming from the same table?

Tags: sql, data-modeling, data-warehouse

If I have only one Client table on my backend.

And then on my cube I create two different dimensiones: PayerClient and SellToClient. But they in fact come from the same source table dbo.Client.

Is there a technical name for these type of dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

If the dimensions refer to the same physical table and are duplicates (apart from the name) then they are called role-playing dimensions